# Java: Print elements of array and insert line break

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking for a way to print an array of integers and insert a line break with a "\" at the end of the line, if the line exceeds 68 elements.

```
for (int i = 0; i<=n.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(n[i]);
     }
```

is used to print each element of the array, but how to I insert the line break and backslash after x (in this case 68) elements?

It should look like this:

146346...8\
37453

Comment: I added some code @Reimus.

Comment: when you say "elements" do you mean the length of the line is 68 or the actual number of items printed is 68 before the "/"

Comment: @LoganMurphy yes, I meant the length of the line. sorry for the unclear expression!

Comment: should the final line end with "/" regardless of size?

Comment: @Cauchy are you expecting all elements from the array to be grouped together before printing them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work for you

```
for (int i = 0; i< n.length; i++) {
     System.out.print(n[i]);
     // every 68 iterations prints a \ and new line
     if((i + 1) % 68 == 0) System.out.println("\\");
}
```

Comment: This code will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on the last iteration. Make sure you fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8+, the Stream API makes for a very fluent alternative to the `for` loop construct:

```
int[] n = ...;
final int limit = 68;

System.out.println(""); // start on a new line

Arrays.stream(n)
      .mapToObj(i -> ((Integer) i).toString()) // convert ints to strings
      .forEach(s -> {
          int i = 0;
          while(i < s.length) {
              System.out.print(s.substring(i, i + limit));
              System.out.println(i + limit < s.length ? "\\" : "");
              i += limit;
          }
      });
```

---

Alternatively, you could do something similar with a `for` loop if you're on an older Java version:

```
int[] n = ...;
final int limit = 68;

System.out.println(""); // start on a new line

for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    String s = Integer.toString(n[i]);
    int i = 0;

    while(i < s.length) {
        System.out.print(s.substring(i, i + limit));
        System.out.println(i + limit < s.length ? "\\" : "");
        i += limit;
    }
}
```

Either way, you just need to first convert the integer to a string, and then print only the substring up to 68 characters in length at a time. `System.out.print` prints output without adding a new line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
int[] intArray = { 7, 9, 5, 1, 3,... };       
for(int i = 0; i<intArray.length; ++i) 
{
// print elements
 System.out.print(intArray[i]);
// if there is 68 element printed, then print \
 if(i % 68 == 0)
  System.out.print("\ \r\n");
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Make sure it's compilable.

Comment: make your if a boolean statement like this `if(i % 68 == 0)` also escape your `\` by using two `\`

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do in two loops

```
    String string = "";
    int size = 68;
    for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        string += n[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length() / size + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(string.substring(i * size, Math.min((i + 1) * size, string.length())));
        System.out.println("\\");
    }
```

Make sure you use `i < n.length` as `i <= n.length` could produce an error in your loop

[Link to code](https://ideone.com/109uIJ)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the help of @elbraulio.

```
for (int i = 0; i<n.length; ++i)
        n[i]=i;
    for (int i = 0; i<n.length; ++i) {
         System.out.print(n[i]);
         if (i%68 == 0 && i !=0) System.out.println("\\");
     }
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: this solution wont work for numbers of length greater than 1, also you should give elbraulio credit if possible, dont just add another answer

Comment: @Cauchy did you tried with my updated answer with i + 1 % 68? It is shorter.